# Database lost on pgadmin after uninstallation - Is my database irretrievably lost?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis, pgadmin-4

I worked on pgadmin 4 and QGIS in localhost port 5432 with version 13 of PostgreSQL creating and updating table in a spatial database. I installed PostgreSQL 14 a few days ago but finally I was not using it, I worked only on PostgreSQL 13 database. So, today, I decided to uninstall PostgreSQL 14. However, after that, I lose all tables and data I've done until then on the database in PostgreSQL 13 and I don't know why because I let PostgreSQL 13 and uninstall only version 14. I cannot access to my work in QGIS as well. Can anybody help me to understand what's happened and is it possible to get back my work and how?

I still have the folder called data from PostgreSQL 13 and 14 in OS. I would like to know if it's possible to extract tables I have done before uninstallation from the data folders of PostgreSQL 14, with files in base.

[Postgres data folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/018xr.png)

[base folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mvle.png)

Thank you if anyone can tell me and how if it's possible.

Comment: I'm afraid your data is gone for good. Possibly you were working on the PostgreSQL 14 all the time without noticing and you uninstalled it in the end. An easy way to see if it was the case is to check the port of both databases and the one you used in pgAdmin ;) good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I look at proprieties and it's weird because I worked initially on port 5432 in PostgreSQL 13 but the port change to 5433. I tried to change it to 5432 but the connection didn't work. I have always the data folder of PostgreSQL 13 and 14 and the folder data of PostgreSQL 14 is more heavy than 13 despite that. I think you're right and I was working these days in PostgreSQL 14 without knowing. Do somebody know if it's possible to extract tables I've done from these folders and how?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'd have to describe exactly how you installed and uninstalled PostgreSQL. The exact operating system and the packages you used are also important.

Comment: You can probably just move the directories to a safe place, reinstall the exact same version and copy the folders back.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I gave up and did it again from the scratch. Thank you all for your comments.